# Reading JSON data in PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing, laravel

I have a JSON object like below, which is stored in a variable called `$product`.

```
{"id":30}
```

When I try to access the stored value though, I get the following error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Here is what I am doing:

```
echo $product->id;
```

Alright folks, sorry for the wild goose chase. Apparently `$products` was an array and not a JSON data, which is really odd because `print_r($products)` and `echo $products` gave different results.

The results can be viewed here:

[image: results]

I am using Laravel, and usually laravel returns a nice JSON object from an SQL query, I must have changed something somewhere, which is why this happened. Thanks.

Comment: Do you test json_decode() after calling json_encode() -- $obj = json_decode(json_encode($product)); echo $obj->id;

Answer (score 1):

Try following **json_decode** function

```
$product = '{"id":30}';
$t = json_decode($product);
echo $t->id;exit;
```

Comment: Doesn't work, gives me an error "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

Comment: If I try json_decode($product, true); then I get the following error "Array to string conversion"

Answer (score 0):

You could use **[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)** to your object.

> Takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable.

**usage**:

```
print_r(json_decode($obj, true));
var_dump(json_decode($obj));
```

Comment: @sarovarc try this `print_r(json_decode($product, true));`

Comment: Give the following error Array to string conversion

Comment: @sarovarc try `print_r($product);`

Comment: Ok there's definitely something odd going on:

Comment: @sarovarc what do you mean ?

Comment: Sorry it was too long to post here: Here is a screenshot of the output: http://i.imgur.com/zD0U5nb.png

Comment: @sarovarc then it means that you are handling an array. What value are you trying to get ?

Comment: @sarovarc that is what I thought glad it helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

Trying below sample :

```
<?php
$product = '{"id": 30}';

$obj = json_decode(json_encode($product));  // or json_decode(json_encode($product), true);
echo $obj->{'id'};  // or echo $obj->id
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first examples are working for me, make sure you PHP is supporting the json_decode() function.
Or you could try this:

```
$product = '{"id":30}';
$t = json_decode($product, true);
echo $t["id"];
```

Passing the true value converts it to an array instead.